# Accurate Arrays oriented upwards

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am modelling the London Eye and I have run into an array problem.

How do I get the capsules to line up accurately in place? I modelled the frame from the same origin but the copies are hard to put in place.

I can't see how to align the floors of my capsules correctly to ground level either

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an array: the duplivert, as the other answer says, will replicate your capsule at every wheel's vertex. Just put the pivot of the duplicated mesh where you want them to be "pinned" to the circle, and clear its origin (this makes wheel's and capsule origine to be in the same point in 3d space).

The other problem you have, align capsules to the ground, can be done in two ways:

The first one is simple, but somewhat limited: select the original capsule and set a "limit rotation" constraint for the wheel rotation axis, to min 0°/ max 0°. Thus, when you rotate the wheel, the dupli-capsules spin around but their "base" keeps parallel to the ground.

like this:

[image]

If you wish your capsule to behave more realistically (eg: individually oscillating to wind, or when the wheel stops) you need to make them real (see CTRL-A menu) and then set up for each some "rigid body" joint to make them behave like real object suspended by real joints... if you need this I'll try to get something to explain.

Here is a hint on how a rigid body constraint could be used for that:

[image: vg]

which, applied to the wheel concept could behave like this:

[image]

Comment: as soon as I set the limit constraint it disables the array

Comment: yes, the whole point is: don't use arrays, use dupliverting...

Comment: I just added a rigid body constraint example that could help if you are willing to do a more dynamic thing..-

Comment: thanks a lot. I don't need any movement but it is good to learn thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem is using **dupliverts**.

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html?highlight=dupliverts

Parent the capsules to a circle and with only the circle selected enable  Duplication vertices in the **Object panel ‣ Duplication ‣ Vertices**. A capsule should be placed at **every vertex of the circle**.

Comment: I am having a big problem here in that when I want to put some messy tarpaulins and cloth stuff into one of the capsules it does not exist in terms of as a collision object