# array rotation while maintaining object rotation

Tags: modeling, modifiers

im currently modelling a ferris wheel with the capsules attached to the rim and i use array modifier to achieve that, although it works with empty object as its offset, the capsules also rotate with the empty object. i actually need the capsules to stay unrotated so it'll looks like gravity is pulling it.
how can i achieve this ? (with array modifier or without array modifier

here's a little image to what i want to achieve
[image: array modifier while maintaining object rotation]

i use dupliverts to achieve this with armature as the controller and it turns out like this :
[image: suggestion#1]

Comment: very similar to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70678/accurate-arrays-oriented-upwards (see my answer there to know how to add dynamic behaviour to rotating capsules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dupliverts to obtain this effect.

[image]

- Create the capsule
- Create a circle composed of 8 vertices as you have 8 capsules
- Make the circle parent of the capsule by selecting both the capsule and the circle (in this order) then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

- Then in the circle's object properties panel check "Verts" in the duplication section.

[image]

Notes :

- The original capsule will not appear in rendering
- The positions of the duplicated capsules will depend on the position of the object's center of the original capsule
- If needed you can rotate the capsules parenting the circle to an armature

[image]

Comment: my armature doesnt work, when i rotate my armature, the whole capsule also rotate , either object mode or pose mode.

Comment: don't parent it as "object", parent it as "Armature deform" then "auto weights"

Comment: check my edited post, that's how it turns out when i move my armature, i've tried parenting my circle to my armature with armature deform then auto weights, still no luck

Comment: for some reason, only 1 vertex is linked to the armature... so do it another way : add all the vertices of the circle to the vertex group created for the bone

Comment: hoh,,i did it, thank you for your comment