# How to spin or rotate same shape

Tags: transforms

I'm making a Ferris wheel. I want my single mesh to rotate in same shape. I array and with the empty I rotated its going in different direction.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion on how to rotate the same shape?

I want to rotate 12 meshes this way

[image]

Comment: Try to use dupliface or dupliframes

Comment: ..or [dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html) on a 9-sided circle.

Comment: see this also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70678/accurate-arrays-oriented-upwards, there's a method to give some more realism to a similar setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or.. using [Dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html)

- Ensure the origin of your gondola is at the point you want to be attached to the wheel.
- Create a 9-sided circle
- Select the gondola, then the circle, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> parent the gondola to the circle
- In the Circle's Object Properties > Duplication panel, check 'Verts' and uncheck 'Rotation'

[image]

As mentioned before, if you want to make the duplicates real, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

This answer doesn't cover how to rig the wheel so when it's rotated, the gondolas swing independently, but I guess that's another question.

EDIT: having read @moonboots' answer... all you have to do to rig it is keep the hierarchy when you make the duplis real (you're given that option), and apply his 'Limit Rotation'  constraint.

Answer (score 2):

you could do it using DupliFrames. At the end, if you want to make each object independent, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, and to make each object independent press <kbd>U</kbd> > Object & Data.

[image]

Comment: Aww cmon, I had such a nice answer prepared already ;-)

Comment: oh sorry, post it anyway  ;)

Comment: No problem at all. Was nearly the same anyway.

Comment: Well, you've taught me something today .. using a Limit Rotation constraint _on top of_  a child relationship is a very different way of doing things than I have been used to in other applications...