# ferris wheel rigid body constrain

Tags: animation, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

So i try to make a ferris wheel but using rigid body physics. The ferris wheel itself using a motor constraint and it work just great.

But when i try to attach the cab with point constrain, well it won't rotate fully anymore and the cab just rotating wildly.

i'm trying to rotate the axis of the constraint but the result still the same. How to make the constraint work properly?.

i attach the blend file so you can see what's wrong.

Edit : i'm not going to manually animate this using a keyframe. But i want the physics do the work. The problem that i encountered is the cab wont follow rotating the motor constraint

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating a Ferris Wheel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108147/animating-a-ferris-wheel)

Comment: i don't want manually animate this, but i want the motor constraint do the work

Comment: see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70678/accurate-arrays-oriented-upwards